# conditional sql query for range of results

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a query that I want to show results differently depending on a specific field.  For example, I am using

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `b`.`company` AS `company`,`bp`.`material` AS `material`,
if(((`bp`.`cost` * 1.2) < `ls`.`maximumbid`),(ROUND(`bp`.`cost` * 1.2,2)),ROUND(`bp`.`cost`,2)) AS `newcost` 
from (((`windows_brands_products` `bp` left join `windows_brands` `b` on((`bp`.`brand_id` = `b`.`id`))) 
join `Windows_last_submissions` `ls`) join `windows_materials` `wm`) 
where ((`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,0)) 
and (`bp`.`height` = round(`ls`.`height`,0))  
and (`bp`.`material` = `wm`.`name`) 
and (`bp`.`type` = `ls`.`type`) 
and if((`ls`.`minimumbid` <> '0.00'),(`bp`.`cost` between `ls`.`minimumbid` and `ls`.`maximumbid`),(`bp`.`cost` <= `ls`.`maximumbid`))) 
ORDER BY b.company ASC");
```

The results I want are if the row `ls`.`type` = 'Fixed/Picture', I want `bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,-1) and still as I have it for any other ls.type

I should be getting correct results from:

```
select `b`.`company` AS `company`,`bp`.`material` AS `material`,if(((`bp`.`cost` * 1.2) < `ls`.`maximumbid`),round((`bp`.`cost` * 1.2),2),round(`bp`.`cost`,2)) AS `newcost` from (((`windows_brands_products` `bp` left join `windows_brands` `b` on((`bp`.`brand_id` = `b`.`id`))) join `Windows_last_submissions` `ls`) join `windows_materials` `wm`) 
where if((`ls`.`type` = 'Fixed/Picture'),(`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,-2),(`bp`.`width` = round(`ls`.`width`,0)) and (`bp`.`height` = round(`ls`.`height`,0)) and (`bp`.`material` = `wm`.`name`) and (`bp`.`type` = `ls`.`type`) and if((`ls`.`minimumbid` <> '0.00'),(`bp`.`cost` between `ls`.`minimumbid` and `ls`.`maximumbid`),(`bp`.`cost` <= `ls`.`maximumbid`))) order by `b`.`company`
```

but it keeps giving me syntax errors as I try to correct the query which I'm not succeeding.

The point is retrieve a broader range of results if the type is 'Fixed/Picture'

Thank you,
Casey

Comment: What language are you using? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot it's a mysql db

Comment: And is the code you are using mysql's stored procedure language, or what?